invalid_grant using Gmail API
I have a node.js backend that uses gmail API to retrieve user emails. The problem is that for some users who recently sign up to use the app they get an "invalid_grant" error after some time. Prior to that the user has no problems, and it doesn't seem to happen to all users.
specifically it happens when I try to call gmail api get but happens in other api calls
await gmail.users.messages.get({
      userId: "me",
      id: id,
      format: "full", // Use 'full' to get the full message content
    });

While looking into this issue, I noticed that for all the cases of invalid_grant the api calls OAuth2Client.refreshTokenNoCache and after that it throws the invalid_grant error. So I'm assuming it has to do with the refresh_token.
This seems to be a common problem and came across this article that discusses it
https://blog.timekit.io/google-oauth-invalid-grant-nightmare-and-how-to-fix-it-9f4efaf1da35#.eqa5iwbkt
Based on it I don't think any of the problems apply to me unless I'm missing something:
These where the common problems:

Server clock/time is out of sync

The code is in a AWS ECS container so I don't believe that's the problem, I think AWS and Google uses the same UTC time

Not authorized for offline access

I authorize using offline

Throttled by Google

I don't believe this is the problem because for cases where quota limits are reached I use an exponential backoff retry and the problem still occurs

Using expired refresh tokens

I don't see how it could be a expired refresh token if it's a new user and the problem happens within the same 1-2 hours of usage

User has been inactive for 6 months

This is happening for new users and they haven't been using the service for 6 months

Use service worker email instead of client ID

For gmail api requests I use the special "me" so I don't think this is an issue

Too many access tokens in short time

I don't believe this is the issue because when the user signs up, I store their access/refresh token in the DB and reuse the same one.

PHP SDK is outdated

I believe this is N/A to me

Incorrect/incomplete refresh token

This could be the case but then why are some new users not having this issue and a few new users are? The same process is being used by everyone

User has actively revoked access to our app

I don't think this is the case because the app is being actively used and I feel like it would be unlikely that the user would immediately revoke permissions

User has reset/recovered Google password

I find this to be improbable that a new user is signing up for a service and then resetting/recovering their google password at the same time and this happens to about 3 users a day
Below I provide more details
Code that causes the error:
async function getMessage(auth, id, retryCount = 0) {
  const gmail = google.gmail({ version: "v1", auth });
  let res;
  const maxRetries = 5; // You can adjust the maximum retries as needed
  try {
    res = await gmail.users.messages.get({
      userId: "me",
      id: id,
      format: "full", // Use 'full' to get the full message content
    });
  } catch (error) {

Stack Trace
Error: invalid_grant
  File "/usr/src/app/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js", line 140, col 23, in Gaxios._request
    throw new common_1.GaxiosError(`Request failed with status code ${translatedResponse.status}`, opts, translatedResponse);
  File "<anonymous>", in runMicrotasks
  File "internal/process/task_queues.js", line 95, col 5, in processTicksAndRejections
  File "/usr/src/app/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js", line 178, col 19, in OAuth2Client.refreshTokenNoCache
    res = await this.transporter.request({
  File "/usr/src/app/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js", line 212, col 19, in OAuth2Client.refreshAccessTokenAsync
    const r = await this.refreshToken(this.credentials.refresh_token);
  File "/usr/src/app/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js", line 421, col 21, in OAuth2Client.requestAsync
    await this.refreshAccessTokenAsync();
  File "/usr/src/app/gmailAPI.js", line 593, col 11, in getMessage
    res = await gmail.users.messages.get({
  File "/usr/src/app/apiManager.js", line 18, col 12, in executeEmailServiceAPI
    return await emailServiceAPI[methodName](...args);
  File "/usr/src/app/apiManager.js", line 310, col 21, in Object.getMessage
    const message = await executeEmailServiceAPI(
  File "/usr/src/app/service.js", line 250, col 25, in processMessage
    const fullMessage = await apiManager.getMessage(

The code below is what I use to create the access and refresh token
///////////
/**
 * Load or request or authorization to call APIs.
 *
 */
async function authorize(emailAccount, updateTokens) {
  try {
    const client = createCredentials(emailAccount, updateTokens);
    if (client) {
      // Ensure the access token is valid before proceeding
      const auth = await ensureValidAccessToken(
        client,
        emailAccount,
        updateTokens
      );
      // Use the client for Google API calls
      return auth;
    } else {
      // Handle the case where no credentials are found
      logger.warn("No credentials found in authorize");
      return null;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error("Error getting email credentials:", err);
    // Handle errors
    return null;
  }
}

function createCredentials(emailAccount, updateTokens) {
  const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    process.env.GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID,
    process.env.GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_SECRET,
    process.env.GOOGLE_API_REDIRECT_URL
  );

  // Create a Google OAuth2 client and set the credentials
  oauth2Client.setCredentials({
    refresh_token: emailAccount.refresh_token,
    access_token: emailAccount.access_token,
    expiry_date: emailAccount.token_expiry,
  });

  oauth2Client.on("tokens", (tokens) => {
    if (tokens.refresh_token) {
      // store the refresh_token in my database!
      try {
        const encryptedAccessToken = encryption.encrypt(tokens.access_token);
        const encryptedRefreshToken = encryption.encrypt(tokens.refresh_token);
        updateTokens(
          emailAccount.id,
          encryptedRefreshToken,
          encryptedAccessToken
        )
          .then(() => logger.info("Tokens updated successfully"))
          .catch((err) => logger.error("Error updating tokens:", err));
      } catch (error) {
        logger.error("Error in token encryption or update:", error);
      }
    }
  });

  return oauth2Client;
}

// This function ensures the access token is valid before making a request
async function ensureValidAccessToken(
  oauth2Client,
  emailAccount,
  updateTokens
) {
  if (
    !oauth2Client.credentials ||
    oauth2Client.credentials.expiry_date <= Date.now()
  ) {
    logger.info("Access token has expired, refreshing token.");
    try {
      const tokens = await oauth2Client.refreshAccessToken();
      oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens.credentials);

      // If tokens are updated, encrypt and store them
      if (tokens.credentials.access_token || tokens.credentials.refresh_token) {
        try {
          const encryptedAccessToken = encryption.encrypt(
            tokens.credentials.access_token
          );
          const encryptedRefreshToken = tokens.credentials.refresh_token
            ? encryption.encrypt(tokens.credentials.refresh_token)
            : emailAccount.refresh_token; // Use the original refresh token if it's not updated

          await updateTokens(
            emailAccount.id,
            encryptedRefreshToken,
            encryptedAccessToken
          );

          logger.info("Tokens refreshed and updated successfully");
        } catch (error) {
          logger.error("Error in token encryption or update:", error);
        }
      }

      return oauth2Client;
    } catch (error) {
      logger.error("Error refreshing access token:", error);
      Sentry.captureException(error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
  return oauth2Client;
}


Your missing one if your app is still in testing refresh tokens expire after seven days

Thank you for your response. My app is in production and has been verified by google.
